# Fiori Launchpad cant start App (negative cache - sap.ui.define is not a function)

Tags: javascript, sapui5

My UI5 app isn't loading anymore when I add additional Parameters in the LPD_CUST.

[Screenshot - SAPUI5.Component Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI0FB.jpg)

Launchpad Error:

`Error - found in negative cache: 'com/untersee/flexnet/supplier/Component.js' from /sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zfn_request/Component.js: TypeError: sap.ui.define is not a function`

The Backend Server is on release 740 with ui5 1.16.3, but since im using online resources from ondemand it shouldnt matter, right?

[Codesnipped of the Component.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG0Xw.jpg)

The weird thing is, when I configure the Launchpad without the additional information for the component it works - but it runs in sandbox mode, which doesn't allow me to get the location hash from the URL for switching between different backend services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved both of my problems.

Updating the Backend solved the `sap.ui.define is not a function` Error.

To get the hash I had to use `parent.location.hash` since the app was running inside an iFrame.